# How to query syntax to match ALL items in a list in LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

What's the LINQ query syntax to find a value if all the list items are found?

Ie,

If I have:

```
UserId, GroupID

1, a
1, b
1, c
2, b
3, a
3, c
```

And my List of user ids that I'm searching for is 1,2, then I only want the group id that has both user id 1 and user id 2 (in this case b)

If I use .contains then I would get back the group id's that contain ANY of user id 1 or 2 (in this case a,b,c

Thanks

Comment: *List of user ids that I'm searching for is 1,2, then I only want the group id that has both user id 1 and user id 2 (in this case b)*. Probably there is a typo error in your data? As I don't see the UserId with 1 has the GroupID: b.

Comment: Maybe you can try [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uxrlOn). Unsure whether it is working in Entity Framework (able to translate from LINQ to SQL) or not. For that case, you may consider to perform the data filter after group by in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following query:

```cs
var idList = new List<int>() {1, 2};

var query = 
    from t in context.SomeTable
    where idList.Contains(t.UserId)
    group t by new { t.GroupID } 
    where g.Count() == idList.Count
    select g.Key.GroupID;
```